# Is there any equivalent for `typeof class` in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
class Student {
    public static sayHello() {
        console.log('hello world');
    }

    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {

    }
}

const static_student1 = Student;
static_student1.sayHello(); // no problem

const static_student2: typeof Student = Student;
static_student2.sayHello(); // no problem
```

But I want to find out something like `StaticClass<T>` to replace `typeof T`.

```
type StaticClass<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

const static_student3: StaticClass<Student> = Student; // this assignment works
static_student3.sayHello(); // but static_student3 does not has sayHello function
```

[typescript-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/zh/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuBXAJgUwHb2gbwLAChojoAHRAIxAEthoJ4x4a6wBPACVRBAHsAKAJQ4CxUdGA90EHiFQA6XgHM+AcgAWXXtADuPAE4hkKgQG4RxAL4FzRCVPh7EwePr5lKzdGAC2qAFx0DlToigA0pBTUtGCK-tDoiN7kqHpCePg20Fb42QR29IGMNAD69CgY8ACM0AC8cEhomGb49EXApQ0VlXIQbJzc-KbQAPTD8TykejyUqN7W+PlYrUztZY3wAEwB8KwkqDwAZvXlmLXH683LJWsVGz19moMmI2PoEyRTM3MZPzt79W0AMLgKAAHgAKgA+M7oVDaaB8ORIsB6RQQAJgdCsADaAF0hDVoeDmnlJAUrqtOpgAMwBBBAkEQUEIE7waF1FkXF7QeBqKgwSAQKiKdC+U66PQAawgBApHVZ1PuHEegmeo2g5EQSwYK3l62p0GQPFQMDeWDUkBYyoG0AOiHQziokiAA)

thanks for any help.

Comment: What's wrong with `typeof T`?

Comment: No，`typeof T` is the right answer. But I wonder is there any other way to achieve the same result.